# Tup -- manually inserting a generated node

Tags: build, tup

Say I have a project A that depends on project B and that B takes a long time to build.

Both project A and project B use tup.
I already have B built in its separate directory.

Can I now copy B into A or create a submodules that points to B, add the build products (`cp -a`), and convince tup that the build products are fine?